# RestController is called before Hibernate creates the database schema

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

Sometimes in integration tests, `RestController` is being called, before Hibernate creates the database schema (using H2 in this case). So, the tests fail because the tables do not yet exist. `ddl-auto` is set to `update`.

How to ensure that the controller is being used *after* the full creation of the database, is there a dependency bean offered by Hibernate the controller can depend on?

The error is something like:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "_USER" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
select u1_0.id,u1_0.company_id,u1_0.country_id,u1_0.created_at,u1_0.created_by,u1_0.disabled,u1_0.email,u1_0.email_confirmed,u1_0.full_access,u1_0.full_name,u1_0.gender,u1_0.mfa,u1_0.mfa_secret,u1_0.modified_at,u1_0.modified_by,u1_0.notification_email,u1_0.notification_slack_webhook,u1_0.notification_slack_webhook_enabled,u1_0.password,u1_0.phone,u1_0.role,u1_0.temp_mfa_secret from _user u1_0 [42104-220]
  at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:514) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8548) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8532) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8521) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.readTablePrimary(Parser.java:1911) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableReference(Parser.java:2391) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2844) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2950) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2834) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2690) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2669) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2662) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2655) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2624) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:732) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:697) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:669) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:577) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:634) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:557) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288) ~[h2-2.2.220.jar:2.2.220]
  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:327) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
  ... 211 common frames omitted
```

Comment: did you try spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create in application.properties ?

Comment: It is `update`. This issue doesn't always reproduce, sometimes the database is created before the controller is called, something after.